# Router: Firewall web filtering blocks more than intended sites

Tags: firewall, router

I use our router's firewall to block certain cites by a "keyword."  For this I put the site's name, such as Facebook, so the for the keyword field, I will put facebook, and it blocks facebook successfully.

However, once I do this I notice other websites becomes slower, sometimes Google doesn't work, we get a 'Method Not Implemented' error, 'Invalid Header', and other issues with totally unrelated sites.

How can I filter out the target site using the router firewall keywords method without affecting other sites?

Comment: Probably would be helpful if you told us what your firewall is, and how you've configured it.

Comment: Can you filter on the URL or the domain instead of filtering on keywords?

Comment: It's a normal home router.  I've tried the domain and the url and get the same result.

Comment: Is this at home or at your office?

Answer (score 2):

Other sites get slower due to the fact that, when doing L7 filtering, your router needs to inspect the contents of each packet instead of just looking at the packet headers. It shouldn't come as a surprise that this additional inspection causes significantly higher load on the router's CPU. You're using a "normal home router", in which case you're dealing with a ridiculously under-powered CPU.